# Change T-SQL Query Using an INSERT with Table Valued Function into a View Instead

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, common-table-expression, table-valued-parameters

The query concerns one table holding Contacts data. A table valued function is used to return the "status" for each Contact.

The insert statement grabs the unique key from the Contacts table and loads it into a variable called @filteredIdList. This is then joined to the Contacts table and again to the table-valued function by passing the variable @filteredIdList into it.

I have simplified the example down to show how I'm currently returning the status. This needs to be changed into a view instead:

```
DECLARE @filteredIdList IdList;
INSERT INTO @filteredIdList SELECT ContactID FROM Contacts

SELECT 
       Contacts.ContactID, 
       Contact_Status

FROM   Contacts
       INNER JOIN @filteredIdList [IDLIST] ON Contacts.ContactID = [IDLIST].[id]
       INNER JOIN tvfContact_Status(@filteredIdList) Contact_Status
       ON [IDLIST].[id] = Contact_Status.ContactID
```

I have tried creating it as a CTE inside the view but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need a view here, but if you want to do this try the below way

Since the `tvfContact_Status` is used to return the status of each contact. Change the `Table valued function` to `Scalar function`.

First alter the `tvfContact_Status` function

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.tvfContact_Status(@ContactID int)
RETURNS varchar(50) --Status
AS 
BEGIN
    --------
    RETURN @Status;
END;
GO
```

Create a `View` like this

```
CREATE VIEW Contact_View
AS
SELECT 
       Contacts.ContactID, 
       dbo.tvfContact_Status(ContactID) as Contact_Status
FROM   Contacts
```

**Note:** This is not a efficient way to do this

Comment: Hi VR46, thanks for the response. These used to be scalar functions that were changed by the vendor to table valued due to performance issues (and they were CLR's/.net runtimes). We have to find a method to handle them as table valued because there are thousands of them (long story).

Comment: @user3491557 - can you add the `tvfContact_Status` code

Comment: I have to do cleanup on the code before I can paste it. Won't have time today but will aim to have something tomorrow. Thank you

Comment: @user3491557 - No issues. After editing the question just comment here. Will look into to it

Answer (score 0):

I believe the CTE you are looking for would be.

```
;with nameofcte (IdList) as (
  select ContactID from Contacts
)
```

then you would just use nameofcte in your join statement.

I do not use CTEs everyday so I normally give this post on Simple Talk a read to refresh myself on them before using them.
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/

Comment: Hi Mike, therein lies the problem. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to pass the result from the CTE into the table valued function. So for example, this does not work:

Comment: WITH Contact_Status (Id)
AS
    (
    select distinct ContactID from Contacts
    )

SELECT  C.ContactID,
    ContactStatus


FROM    Contacts C
    INNER JOIN Contact_Status on Contact_Status.Id = C.ContactID
    INNER JOIN dbo.tvfContact_Status(Contact_Status.Id) ContactStatus ON Contact_Status.Id = C.ContactID

Comment: It says:     Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
The multi-part identifier "Contact_Status.Id" could not be bound.

Comment: Try a sub-select dbo.tvfContact_Status(select Id from Contact_Status) You may need a top 1 on the sub-select but from the sample it seems to only return one value.

Comment: The initial query I gave returns thousands of rows, which it should and what I want the new query to do also. In regards to trying it with the sub select, the function doesn't seem to know what do with that: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 83
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.